# Why did everyone call the organization S.H.I.E.L.D in Captain Marvel?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, dialogue, iron-man, captain-marvel

There was a fun running gag in *Iron Man* (2008) where Agent Coulson keeps calling his organization the Strategic Homeland Intervention, Enforcement and Logistics Division. Pepper Potts says that's quite a mouthful, and he says "I know, we're working on it."

But in *Captain Marvel*, set in 1995, well before *Iron Man* took place, Agent Coulson and Nick Fury casually refer to the organization as S.H.I.E.L.D. many times.

Did they use the abbreviation just to simplify things for the audience? Was this a production gaffe? What's going on here?

Comment: There are lots of sources in the MCU that call it "S.H.I.E.L.D" - most notably, the TV show *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* (also starring Agent Phil Coulson.)

Comment: @Steve-O the point of the question is why the 1995 version has the abbreviation, while the 2008 version uses the full name and *"is working on it"*

Comment: Well, the full name is indeed a mouthful, but at the end of the movie, when Pepper thanks Coulson and starts saying the full name, he interrupts her and says: [__"Just call us S.H.I.E.L.D."__](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/quotes/qt0478078).

Comment: Speculatively answered on SCIFI: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60519/why-didnt-phil-introduce-himself-as-being-with-s-h-i-e-l-d-from-the-beginning

Answer (score 7):

It's not reasoned anywhere within the MCU, or outside of it to my knowledge but if we look at how it's used in the films:

**Out of Universe:** it was a nice nod to those who knew or bothered to work out the acronym in Iron Man, and those that didn't get a nice intro at the end, S.H.I.E.L.D. is a major part of Marvel's comics. and using it's full name was a way to reward the knowing audience without removing anything from the unknowning

**In Universe:** as Dave linked in the comments above to Horuskol speculative answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60519/why-didnt-phil-introduce-himself-as-being-with-s-h-i-e-l-d-from-the-beginning) the full name is given to civilians, whereas government groups are given the abbreviated name S.H.I.E.L.D. After that in the films S.H.I.E.L.D. is used always, but no civilians (at least none below security clearance) are given it either.

Answer (score 3):

In the comics, what S.H.I.E.L.D stands for has changed over time, it is possible that this is also true in the MCU, so when Coulson says "We're working on it", he may mean the underlying name rather than the acronym.

In *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D* s1e1, Grant Ward alludes to this; when asked what Strategic Homeland Intervention, Enforcement and Logistics Division meant, he says something along the lines of 'Someone really wanted it to spell S.H.I.E.L.D'